# How to make a hyper video?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, hyperlink

Hyper video is video which can:

1. Have links or "clickable objects or interfaces" in the video, that can be clicked, and clicking those takes you to the page or object the URL of the link points to.
2. Be searched by its contents. So if you remember a dialogue spoken in a hyper video, you can search the web for this video , by this dialogue or part of that dialogue.

At the conceptual level, these "links" can be normal hyperlinks or even objects in the video like a chair or a table. So clicking on the table (when it comes in the video), will take you to an information page about the video. You can view the demo here: http://insidescience.open-hypervideo.org/sequence/6 . But the creator of this project has not released the product yet, and has not mentioned how he has done it. My understanding is that you can specify the entire video by using XML,HTML,CSS3,JS.

**My question:** How exactly does one make a hyper video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have links or "clickable objects or interfaces" in the video, that can be clicked, and clicking those takes you to the page or object the URL of the link points to.

Start with [HTML 5 video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video), then [listen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event#DOM_event_handler_List) for [play events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Media_events) to figure out when to [add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) and [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild) the interactive elements which you [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) over the video.

> Be searched by its contents. So if you remember a dialogue spoken in a hyper video, you can search the web for this video , by this dialogue or part of that dialogue.

That's a matter of having a timed transcription of the dialogue video, and searching it like any other content. This would usually involve server side technologies though.

Comment: So, I show a normal video using HTML5; use listeners for identifying when the video is played or possibly how much time has elapsed in the video; Then , when the moment is correct, let's say 20 seconds of the video has elapsed, I use JS, to float a "link" object over the video. Right? I don't know if that's how they make a hyper video because I thought the links would be part of the video somehow, while making it, but this is an excellent solution to achieve the same result :) thanks Quentin!

Comment: Yes; yes, play events have the elapsed time attached to them; absolute positioning is likely to be a better choice than floating. You can't embed links into a video per se, the closest I've seen is DVD / MKV menus where the container format describes the active areas - and browsers don't support any external formats that provide that feature, using JS to add HTML elements is exactly the same principle though.